# VsCode Task open new terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration

So, at work, we have to run a script on which we can use 'make build' to compile the project. I want to open VS Code and run this script at startup in the integrated terminal (which I have done), and run another task which will write 'make build' in the integrated terminal to compile. The issue is whenever I run the second task, it opens a new terminal that doesn't have the script executed. I don't want to execute the initial script every time. How can I configure the second script to run in the same terminal?

Here is a similar tasks.json which reproduces the problem.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",

    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "startup",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "python",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "shared"
            },
            "runOptions": {"runOn": "folderOpen"}
        },
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "print('hello')",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always",
                "panel": "shared",
            }
        },
    ]
}
```